# How to add two javascript files in a shortcode in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I am creating a **shortcode** in the `functions.php` WordPress, So that I can add my javaScript file in shortcode to call it on my website page.

Comment: check my ans plz, plz upvote and select as correct answer if it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend adding it this way first you have to register the script using wp_register_script()

```
function your_shortcode_wp_enqueue_scripts_fun() {

    wp_register_script( 'cus-js1',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_shortcode_wp_enqueue_scripts_fun');
```

After that you have call it in your shortcode using wp_enqueue_script()

```
function get_specific_product_shortcode_function($atts){

    extract( shortcode_atts(
        array(
           'id' => '',
            ), $atts )
    );

    ob_start();


    ...
    wp_enqueue_script('cus-js1');
    ...




return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('get_specific_product_shortcode', 'get_specific_product_shortcode_function');
```

This is the right way to that

Answer (score 2):

You can add short code and output the content of the short parameter like this

```
function stackoverflow_60004550( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'path' => 'default-path.js',
        ), $atts, 'path' );

    return '<script type="text/javascript" src="'.$atts['path'].'"></script>';
}
add_shortcode( 'jsshortcode', 'stackoverflow_60004550' );
```

You can then use it like this in your posts where you want to show the output path:

```
[jsshortcode path="https://example.com/complete-path.js"]
```

This can work on both page and post content as explained here: https://nabtron.com/how-to-add-javascript-file-in-wordpress-shortcode/

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise adding it this way. The shortcode is actually added shortly after the rest of the page is rendered. Instead I would add the javascript via wp_enqueue_scripts on the specific page you want to add it to. Add this to your function:

```
function load_scripts() {

   global $post;

   if( is_page() || is_single() )
   {
       switch($post->post_name) // post_name is the post slug
       {
           case 'some-page-slug-here':
               wp_enqueue_script('about', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/some-js-file.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
               break;

       }
   } 
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');
```